# Regressing on residuals of linear mixed model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, mixed-model, linear

So for a linear mixed model like this:

$y=X\beta+Zu+e$

I can estimate the BLUP for $u$:

$\hat{u}=GZ^TV^{-1}(y-X\hat{\beta})$

Where $G$ is the co-variance matrix of $u$ and $V=ZGZ^T+R$, where $R$ is the co-variance matrix of $e$. And where $G=\sigma^2_uK$ and $R=\sigma_e^2I$. Let us say that $Z$ is the identity matrix and that we therefore have a linear mixed model with only a random intercept.

Let us say that I first estimate this model ($X'$ are covariates not including the term we want to test):

$y=X'\beta' + u +e$

Would it be the same to do the following (where we do not update $\sigma^2_u$ and $\sigma_e^2$ because we assume that each variable we want to test has little influence on this - so this is an approximation):

$y=X\beta+u+e$

And then doing this where we estimate the BLUP for $\hat{u}$, using $X'\beta'$ ($\hat{u}$ should stay the same for each variable we test, under our assumptions):

$(y-\hat{u})=X\beta+e$

Is that equivalent? And if not why? And is there any way of having a linear model "imitate" a linear mixed model where the intercept is the only random term?

EDIT:

The **goal** is to be able to run this model with the variance components ($\sigma^2_u$, $\sigma^2_e$) estimated under the null hypothesis (without our tested term) - this is because I have a lot of tests and I want to speed up this analysis. As I would not have to re-estimate the variance components for each new test:

$y=X\beta+u+e$

I then want to hear if this model is equivalent to the one just mentioned, in this one I estimate the BLUP $\hat{u}$ under the null model (without our tested term) and I then do an ordinary least squares on this:

$(y-\hat{u})=X\beta+e$

EDIT2:

I just want to run test for a lot of different data points, independently, where I would just exchange one column of the design matrix $X$. This can not be solved including additional random effects.

Comment: It is not very clear what you’re trying to accomplish-could you provide more information?

Comment: Can you say more about these many different tests you want to run? Might you be able to incorporate them into the mixed model as a non-nested factor (i.e., as a second or third random intercept that is not strictly nested within subjects or whatever your groups are)?